# Reference non asp checkbox in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to reference a non-asp check box in C# code behind. The reason the checkbox is not an asp element, is it gets auto-generated on the fly, rather than being a part of the website. So far I have the following relevant aspx:

```
<asp:Table ID="myTable" runat="server" Width="100%"> 
    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell>A</asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell>B</asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell>C</asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell>D</asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell>E</asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="TEST" CssClass="btn btn-default pull-right" OnClick="TEST_Click">
    TEST <i class="m-icon-swapright m-icon-white"></i>
</asp:LinkButton>
```

And the C# code behind is:

```
    public void GenerateTable()
    {
        int i = 0;
        bool[] box = {true, false, true, false, true};
        List<TableRow> tRows = new List<TableRow>();
        TableRow newRow = new TableRow();
        tRows.Add(newRow);
        foreach (var check in box)
            {
                TableCell tempCell = new TableCell();
                if (check)
                {
                    tempCell.Text = "<input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"chk" + i + "\" >";
                }
                else
                {
                    tempCell.Text = "<input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"chk" + i + "\" checked>";
                }
                tRows[0].Cells.Add(tempCell);
                i++;
        }

        foreach (TableRow row in tRows)
        {
            myTable.Rows.Add(row);
        }
    }


    public void TEST_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        HtmlInputCheckBox chkbox = (HtmlInputCheckBox)FindControl("chk1");
        if (chkbox != null)
        {
            if (!chkbox.Checked)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Checked");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("NOT Checked");
            }
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("NOTHING :(");
    }
```

chkbox is always null :(.

Comment: Please wrap it in like an <asp:Panel ID="Pnl" runat="server"> first and use Pnl.FindControl("chk1");

Comment: Is this a stand-alone .aspx page, or does it have a master page? The latter has a tendency to change the generated ID. Can you edit an example of the rendered input?

Comment: I have tried Robs suggestion, and it worked but only with checkboxes manually added in the aspx. It does have a master page, I have updated how the checkboxes are added. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to change two things.

In order to find a checkbox via `FindControl` it must be part of the pages control collection, which means you have to add a `CheckBox`control.

```
CheckBox c = new CheckBox { ID = "chk"  + i };                
tempCell.Controls.Add(c);
```

The dynamically added `CheckBox` control is part of the control collection of the `Table`, so you'll have to search for it there instead of on the page.

```
CheckBox chkbox = (CheckBox)this.myTable.FindControl("chk1");
```

Below you find a full update of your code.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GenerateTable();
}


public void GenerateTable()
{
    int i = 0;
    bool[] box = {true, false, true, false, true};
    List<TableRow> tRows = new List<TableRow>();
    TableRow newRow = new TableRow();
    tRows.Add(newRow);
    foreach (var check in box)
    {
        TableCell tempCell = new TableCell();
        CheckBox c = new CheckBox { ID = "chk"  + i };
        c.Checked = check;
        tempCell.Controls.Add(c);                    

        tRows[0].Cells.Add(tempCell);
        i++;
    }

    foreach (TableRow row in tRows)
    {
        myTable.Rows.Add(row);
    }
}


public void TEST_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox chkbox = (CheckBox)this.myTable.FindControl("chk1");
    if (chkbox != null)
    {
        if (!chkbox.Checked)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Checked");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("NOT Checked");
        }
    }
    else 
    {           
        MessageBox.Show("NOTHING :(");                           
    }
}
```